# Assigning a value having semicolon (';') to a variable in bash

Tags: shell, unix, sed, escaping

I'm trying to escape ('\') a semicolon (';') in a string on unix shell (bash) with sed. It works when I do it directly without assigning the value to a variable. That is,

```
$ echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'
hello\;
$
```

However, it doesn't appear to work when the above command is assigned to a variable:

```
$ result=`echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'`
$ 
$ echo $result
hello; 
$
```

Any idea why?

I tried by using the value enclosed with and without quotes but that didn't help. Any clue greatly appreciated.

btw, I first thought the semicolon at the end of the string was somehow acting as a terminator and hence the shell didn't continue executing the `sed` (if that made any sense). However, that doesn't appear to be an issue. I tried by using the semicolon not at the end of the string (somewhere in between). I still see the same result as before. That is,

```
$ echo "hel;lo" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'
hel\;lo
$
$ result=`echo "hel;lo" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'`
$
$ echo $result
hel;lo
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it interesting that the use of back-ticks gives one result (your result) and the use of `$(...)` gives another result (the wanted result):

```
$ echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'
hello\;
$ z1=$(echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g')
$ z2=`echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'`
$ printf "%s\n" "$z1" "$z2"
hello\;
hello;
$
```

If ever you needed an argument for using the modern `x=$(...)` notation in preference to the older `` x=`...` `` notation, this is probably it.  The shell does an extra round of backslash interpretation with the back-ticks.  I can demonstrate this with a little program I use when debugging shell scripts called `al` (for 'argument list'); you can simulate it with `printf "%s\n"`:

```
$ z2=`echo "hello;" | al sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g'`
$ echo "$z2"
sed
s/\([^\]\);/\1\;/g
$ z1=$(echo "hello;" | al sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g')
$ echo "$z1"
sed
s/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g
$ z1=$(echo "hello;" | printf "%s\n" sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g')
$ echo "$z1"
sed
s/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g
$
```

As you can see, the script executed by `sed` differs depending on whether you use  `x=$(...)` notation or `` x=`...` `` notation.

```
s/\([^\]\);/\1\;/g            # ``
s/\([^\\]\);/\1\\;/g          # $()
```

#### Summary

Use `$(...)`; it is easier to understand.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the explnation. You are right. shell needed an extra set of backslashes (something like `sed 's/\([^\\\\]\);/\1\\\\;/g'`) to get the desired result. Also, $(...) option works great.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `sed` (or any other regex engine) for this at all:

```
s='hello;'
echo "${s//;/\;}"
```

This is a [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) which replaces `;` with `\;`.

That said -- why are you trying to do this? In most cases, you don't want escape characters (which are syntax) to be inside of scalar variables (which are data); they only matter if you're parsing your data as syntax (such as using eval), which is a bad idea for other reasons, and best avoided (or done programatically, as via `printf %q`).

Comment: 'paramter expansion' is nice! i didn't know this at all. Thanks!  I'm reading a list of regexes to convert them to snort rules. For some reason, snort doesn't compile a rule unless the semicolons are escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use four (three also work). I guess its because it's interpreted twice, first one by the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command and the second one by the shell when reading the content of the variable:

```
result=`echo "hello;" | sed 's/\([^\\]\);/\1\\\\;/g'`
```

And

```
echo "$result"
```

yields:

```
hello\;
```

Comment: yep, I figured while trying the options suggested by Jonathan Leffler (above). Thanks.